# Passing argument to docker run command

Tags: docker, jekyll

I am running the following command to start up Jekyll with my locally checked out Jekyll-based site:

```
docker run -p 4000:4000 --volume=$PWD:/srv/jekyll \ 
-it jekyll/jekyll:$JEKYLL_VERSION jekyll serve
```

This works just fine. However, when I pass it the `--baseurl` argument like this:

```
docker run -p 4000:4000 --volume=$PWD:/srv/jekyll \ 
-it jekyll/jekyll:$JEKYLL_VERSION jekyll serve --baseurl ''
```

Everything runs fine again, until it gets to this point:

```
> docker run -p 4000:4000 --volume=$PWD:/srv/jekyll -it jekyll/jekyll:$JEKYLL_VERSION jekyll serve --baseurl ''
Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.15.3). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
The following gems are missing
 * jekyll (3.5.0)
Install missing gems with `bundle install`
Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.15.3). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Using public_suffix 2.0.5
Using bundler 1.15.2
Using colorator 1.1.0
Using ffi 1.9.18
Using forwardable-extended 2.6.0
Using rb-fsevent 0.10.2
Using kramdown 1.14.0
Using liquid 4.0.0
Using mercenary 0.3.6
Using rouge 1.11.1
Using safe_yaml 1.0.4
Using jekyll-paginate 1.1.0
Using addressable 2.5.1
Using rb-inotify 0.9.10
Using pathutil 0.14.0
Using sass-listen 4.0.0
Using listen 3.0.8
Using sass 3.5.1
Using jekyll-watch 1.5.0
Using jekyll-sass-converter 1.5.0
Fetching jekyll 3.5.0
Installing jekyll 3.5.0
Using jekyll-feed 0.9.2
Bundle complete! 3 Gemfile dependencies, 22 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
The latest bundler is 1.15.3, but you are currently running 1.15.2.
To update, run `gem install bundler`
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/program.rb:31:in `go': missing argument: --baseurl (OptionParser::MissingArgument)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary.rb:19:in `program'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/jekyll-3.5.0/exe/jekyll:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/bin/jekyll:22:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/jekyll:22:in `<main>'
```

Why is this happening and how do I pass the `--basepath` argument to the jekyll command? Seems like I am doing something wrong with docker, which I am new to.

Thanks!

Comment: Try with --baseurl '/' or removing it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the docs at https://docs.docker.com/v1.7/reference/run/#env-environment-variables you can pass it in with the docker run command with the -e parameter.

This is what I tested in a simple run script:

```
# Start Jekyll and watch for changes
docker run --rm -it \
    -e JEKYLL_ENV=production \
    --volume=/$(pwd):/srv/jekyll \
    --publish 4000:4000 \
    $DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME
```

The image is simply grahamc/jekyll. I tried adding -e BASEURL="" \ to the docker run command above. However I found that if there was a baseurl set in _config.yml, that setting won over the environment setting.

Comment: That requires defining that variable in a Dockerfile, doesn't it? How would I be able to run `--bashurl ''` just simple command line?